# how to update data from input box to observable list

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am designing a shopping cart.
The list of products (prodList) is shown to customer, when a user click on "Add" button, the respective product is shown in shopping cart list(orderList).

The Qty column for product added on orderList is a input box of type text.
I have one increment button (+) and decrement button(-), to update the Qty.

Now what I want is when user input a number directly into the input box, the same should get reflected.

I know I need to try with observable element, but I am unable to get it working, any suggestion, tips are also welcomed.

Below is the code

HTML For prodList

```
<div class="lifticons" data-bind="foreach: prodList">
    <div class="iIconGrid2" align= "center">
        <a  href="#" data-bind="click: $root.addToCart">
            <img class="iImageTags" alt="Juices" data-bind="attr: {src: imgPath}">
        </a>
        <a href="#"><div class="linkProdName" data-bind="click: $root.addToCart, text: ProductName"></div></a>
        <div class="ProdPrice"><label>Rs </label><label data-bind="text: ProductPrice" id="lblPrice"></label></div>
        <div class="productAdd2"><button class="button" data-bind="click: $root.addToCartViaProdList">Add</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML for orderList

```
<div data-bind="foreach: orderList">
    <div class="OrderData"data-bind="visible: ProductQty">
        <div class="horDiv0" data-bind="text: ProductName"></div>
        <div class="horDiv25"><span><label>Rs </label><label data-bind="text: ProductPrice"></label></span></div>
        <div class="horDivQty">
            <a href="#"><label class="minusCircle" data-bind="click: $root.removeFromList">-</label></a>
            <input class="editQty"type="text" data-bind="value: ProductQty"/>
            <a href="#"><label class="minusCircle" data-bind="click: $root.addToCartViaOrderList">+</label></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

KNOCKOUT CODE

```
function ProdList(ProductID, ProductName, ProductPrice, ProductCartDesc, ProductCategoryID, ProductQty)
{
    this.ProductID = ko.observable(ProductID);
    this.ProductName = ko.observable(ProductName);
    this.ProductPrice = ko.observable(ProductPrice);
    this.ProductCartDesc = ko.observable(ProductCartDesc);
    this.ProductCategoryID = ko.observable(ProductCategoryID);
    this.ProductQty = ko.observable(ProductQty);


}
function ProdListViewModel(prods)
{   
    var self = this;
    self.prodList = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

    self.orderList = ko.computed(function()
    {
        var orderedItems = [];
        /*Save data if browser is closed, still the data of cart will be retrievable*/
            if (self.remOrAdd() == "FINISH")
            {
                localStorage.removeItem("orderListDemo");
                return orderedItems;
            }

            if (localStorage.getItem("orderListDemo") != null)
            {
                var orderListSaved = [];
                var dataSaved = ko.utils.parseJson(localStorage.getItem("orderListDemo"));

                orderListSaved = ko.utils.arrayMap(dataSaved, function(item)
                {
                    return new ProdList(item.ProductID, item.ProductName, item.ProductPrice, item.ProductCartDesc, item.ProductCategoryID, item.ProductQty);
                });

                for(var ctrOrderListSaved = 0 ; ctrOrderListSaved < orderListSaved.length ; ctrOrderListSaved++)
                {
                    if (orderListSaved[ctrOrderListSaved].ProductQty() > 0)
                    {
                        orderedItems.push(orderListSaved[ctrOrderListSaved]);
                    }
                }
            }

            /*Checks whether to increment or decrement the QTY*/
            var ctrOrderedItems = 0;
            var trackIndex = 0;
            var index = -1;
            var loopTracker = 0;

            if(self.remOrAdd().length > 3)
                index = parseInt(self.remOrAdd().substring(3));

            if (self.remOrAdd().indexOf("ADD") > -1 && index > -1)
            {
                $(self.prodList()).each(function(i,e){


                    if (index > -1 && index == e.ProductID())
                    {
                        for(ctrOrderedItems = 0; ctrOrderedItems < orderedItems.length; ctrOrderedItems++)
                        {
                            if (e.ProductID() == orderedItems[ctrOrderedItems].ProductID())
                            {
                                orderedItems[ctrOrderedItems].ProductQty(orderedItems[ctrOrderedItems].ProductQty() + 1);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (ctrOrderedItems >= orderedItems.length)
                        {
                            orderedItems.push(e);
                            orderedItems[orderedItems.length-1].ProductQty(1);

                        }
                    }

                    loopTracker++;

                });
            }

            if (self.remOrAdd().indexOf("REM") > -1 && index > -1)
            {
                if (orderedItems.length > 0)
                    if (orderedItems[index].ProductQty() > 1)
                        orderedItems[index].ProductQty(orderedItems[index].ProductQty() - 1);
                    else
                        orderedItems.splice(index,1);

            }

        localStorage.removeItem("orderListDemo");

        self.viewOrderTab(0);
        if (orderedItems.length > 0)
        {
            localStorage.setItem("orderListDemo", ko.toJSON(orderedItems));
            self.viewOrderTab(1);

        }




        return orderedItems;
    },this);    


    self.addToCartViaProdList = function (item, event) 
    {
        /*get current item index*/
        /*in dom element $index() is enough but in viewModel a context is to be obtained*/

        var context = ko.contextFor(event.target);
        var index = context.$index();
        var incQty = self.prodList()[index].ProductQty();
        var prodID = self.prodList()[index].ProductID();
        incQty++;
        self.remOrAdd("");
        self.remOrAdd("ADD"+prodID);

    };

    self.addToCartViaOrderList = function (item, event) 
    {


        var context = ko.contextFor(event.target);
        var index = context.$index();

        //Assumption this button can only be clicked only when the saved data storage is available.
        var orderListSaved = [];
        var dataSaved = ko.utils.parseJson(localStorage.getItem("orderListDemo"));

        orderListSaved = ko.utils.arrayMap(dataSaved, function(item)
        {
            return new ProdList(item.ProductID, item.ProductName, item.ProductPrice, item.ProductCartDesc, item.ProductCategoryID, item.ProductQty);
        });

        var prodID = orderListSaved[index].ProductID();



        self.remOrAdd("");
        self.remOrAdd("ADD"+prodID);
    };

    self.removeFromList = function(item, event)
    {
        var context = ko.contextFor(event.target);
        var index = context.$index();

        self.remOrAdd("");
        self.remOrAdd("REM"+index);

    };
}

var prodListViewModel = new ProdListViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(prodListViewModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, check the snippet below, whatever value you enter into text box, it will increment from there only. There might be an issue with parsing in your code.

And try to give a simple code next time which can be understood and run easily.
Also your code is complex, try to break it into different module, do not add this much code in one single file.

```js
   function AppViewModel() {

     this.ProductQty = ko.observable(0);

     this.removeFromList = function() {
       var currentVal = parseInt(this.ProductQty());
       if (currentVal >= 1) {
         this.ProductQty(currentVal - 1);
       }
     };

     this.addToCartViaOrderList = function() {
       var currentVal = parseInt(this.ProductQty());
       if (isNaN(currentVal)) {
         currentVal = 0;
       }
       this.ProductQty(currentVal + 1);
     };
   }

    // Activates knockout.js
   ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```css
.qty {
  font-size: 38px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="qty">
  <a href="#">
    <label data-bind="click: $root.removeFromList">-</label>
  </a>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: ProductQty" />
  <a href="#">
    <label data-bind="click: $root.addToCartViaOrderList">+</label>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Parshii. I tried your approach and it works. The complexity here arises because of two reason: 1. I need to preserve the data selected. 2. If user moves on to different category then prodList will have data as per that category. Any previous data will be erased. Hence to have above feature the code gets complex.

Comment: No Problem, may you make the best app for your business, also feel free to mark it as an answer. @DashmeetSingh